# What's stopping the derivative of $f(x)g(x)$ from equaling $f(x)g'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

What am I not understanding about how limits work? Please help me understand what's wrong with this proof.

$f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions of $x$, and are therefore continuous.
\begin{align*}
\frac d{dx}\left[ f(x)g(x)\right] &= \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)g(x+dx)-f(x)g(x)}{dx} &&\text{1. Definition of derivative}\\
&= \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)g(x+dx)}{dx}-\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{dx} &&\text{2. Difference of limits}\\
&= \lim_{dx\to 0}f(x+dx) \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{g(x+dx)}{dx}-\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{dx} &&\text{3. Product of limits}\\
&= \lim_{dx\to 0}f(x) \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{g(x+dx)}{dx}-\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{dx} &&\text{4. Definition of continuity}\\
&= \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x+dx)}{dx}-\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{dx} &&\text{5. Product of limits}\\
&= \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x+dx)-f(x)g(x)}{dx} &&\text{6. Difference of limits}\\
&= \lim_{dx\to 0}f(x)\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{g(x+dx)-g(x)}{dx} &&\text{7. Product of limits}\\
&= f(x)\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{g(x+dx)-g(x)}{dx} &&\text{8. Limit evaluated}\\
&= f(x)g'(x) &&\text{9. Definition of derivative}\\
\end{align*}
Please note that I already know what the actual product rule is and how to prove it, so that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking why the proof I wrote above doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your answers in the answers section. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=F$ exists and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=G$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=F+G$.

However, it is not legitimate to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ as in the OP since neither the limit $\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)g(x+dx)}{dx}$ nor the limit $\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{dx}$ exists in general.

We can write, however, that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)g(x+dx)-f(x)g(x)}{dx}&=\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)g(x+dx)-f(x+dx)g(x)}{dx}\\\\
&+\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{f(x+dx)g(x)-f(x)g(x)}{dx}\\\\
&=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)
\end{align}$$

since we are assuming that both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable.

Comment: Can you tell why they don't exist in general?

Comment: @user36790: "They don't exist in general" because the numerator is a constant and denominator $dx$ is tending to $0$. If the numerator is $0$ then the limit is $0$ otherwise the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand now that the problem is that certain properties of limits only apply when the individual limits exist, and so I need to be careful to make sure they exist. My textbook wasn't too clear about that, so as far as I could tell I was applying the properties acceptably. There's far too much in the book that just takes us through the steps of what we can do with limits, and far too little that warns against what we can't do.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that unless $f(x) = 0$ or $g(x) = 0$,

$$\lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{dx}$$

does not exist. Hence, there's already a problem at line $2$.

---

Two comments:

- There's a similar issue with the first pair of limits on line two; unless $f'$ or $g'$ has a zero at $x$, the limit doesn't exist.
- If the limits do exist, then that's precisely the condition where at least one of the two halves of $f'g + g'f$ disappear (which is also suggestive of where the problem in the proof lies...).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're referring to as the first pair of limits on line two, and how they apply to $f'$ and $g'$?

Answer (score 1):

Wow!
I find it amazing how wrong this is.

By steps:

2. Wrong because you can't split
   the limit into separate terms.
   The two terms you have
   are both infinite -
   a finite amount divided by $dx$.
3. You can't separate the
   product terms out
   until you prove that
   the limits exist.
   You could just as well
   separate out
   $g(x+dx)$
   and get $f'(x)g(x)$
   as your final result.

4-5. You pulled $f(x+dx)$ out,
removed the $dx$,
and put it back,
with the term
always being infinite.
Oy.

6. You took two infinite terms
   and put them back together
   inside a limit.
7. You pulled $f(x)$ out
   and, even though it does not
   contain $dx$,
   put it in a limit.
8. You took a limit
   with respect to a variable
   ($dx$) that isn't there.
9. This is correct,
   assuming the result of
   step 8 is correct,
   which, of course,
   it isn't.

Comment: -1: While this is a good answer for the most part, I think it would be better to adjust the tone to be more friendly. The original poster has put effort into writing a good question and is clearly learning; they do not deserve condescension. Also there is no problem with taking limits of quantities constant w.r.t. the limit variable, as you take issue with in step 7 and 8.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. I know that my proof was wrong. I didn't mean to propose it as something true, so I hope you didn't take offense.

Comment: No offense taken. I was just alarmed at the misunderstandings shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your second step is nonsense. The two limits would both have to exist in order that this be valid.